# seperat shape painted by 0 and 1 array

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap, microcontroller, paint

I have text file contain array of 0s and 1s.
Its width is 64 and I want to convert it to 32 pixel but keep shape painted by it is visible.

I tried to take one and delete one.
But that makes shape not visible.

I tried to sum every two pixels but code doesn´t work.
It gives me an empty array.

This is my function:

```
string[] halfColumnsAndRawsArray = new string[halfRawsArray.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < halfRawsArray.Length; i ++)
{
    char[] beforeEditingStr = halfRawsArray[i].ToCharArray();
    char[] afterEditingStr = new char[beforeEditingStr.Length / 2];
    int c = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < beforeEditingStr.Length; j += 2)
    {
        int jj = j + 1;
        //if ((j % 2) == 0)
        //{
        int sum = (Convert.ToInt16(beforeEditingStr[j]) + Convert.ToInt16(beforeEditingStr[jj]));
        if (sum == 2) sum = 1;
        afterEditingStr[c] = Convert.ToChar(sum);
        c++;
        //}
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < afterEditingStr.Length; k++)
    {
        halfColumnsAndRawsArray[i] += afterEditingStr[k];
    }
    halfColumnsAndRawsArray[i] += ",   ";
}
```

The main goal of this function to convert black and white bitmap to 0s and 1s string array.
That makes me able to use it in microcontrollers.

My program is ready and just waiting for this function.

before this i used function to convert a bitmap to 0s and 1s array
and saved it to text file
then i should get this shap are painted from 0s and 1s smaller

array is 16×64
and i want to convert it to
16×32 but the shape are painted by this array shuold still understandable by eyes

Comment: In your `i` loop you skip every second line. Is this intended? Suggestion: Start a debugging session by converting a 2x8 image to an 2x4 one. The involved number of pixels to be followed is more handy and you can cross check your resizing on paper

Comment: first bart about +=2 is fault from me, i changed it, but secound part it i should convert it after get the array because very small sizes makes pictures ununderstandable so i should use this function